# Initializing a StreamingKmeans model with static training data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I can construct a Spark Kmeans model using a training dataset. I would like to make my model adapt to new data, so Spark StreamingKmeans seems great for me.

However, it appears that Spark's StreamingKmeans can only be trained on streamed in data. There is no way to initialize it with a default kmeans model, trained on some static training data, and then train the model on new streamed-in data over time.

Does there exist a way to initialize a KMeans model in Spark using static training data, AND train it over time on new data using StreamingKmeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [StreamingKMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans) has a `setInitialCenters(centers: Array[Vector], weights: Array[Double])` method.  And the statically trained [KMeansModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel) has a `clusterCenters(): Array[Vector]` method.  So you can initialize a StreamingKMeans with the `clusterCenters()` of a pre-trained KMeansModel.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to that static training data, you can send that to the StreamingKMeans in a DStream; otherwise, I don't think there's another way to initialize the StreamingKMeans object.